# Getting Errs 'running setup.py install for numpy" Anyone have a simple numpy-site.cfg or site.cfg on Windows and Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy

Using Windows 8 / Python 2.7 / 
Have tried to rewrite site.cfg and numpy-site.cfg but there are many factors.

- 1.Is there a simple site.cfg somewhere?

  2. I've installed numpy from several urls so I'm probably overwriting things and there may be version discrepencies. However, the err
     message below indicates it might be calling from the site.cfg. Not
     the Numpy install itself?
  3. Also have installed gFortran for the Fortran compiler.
  4. Eventually need Atlas, Lapack too ( missing )

Am a little fuzzy on how all the libraries fit together but am piecing them together.  Your help would be appreciated!

Running setup.py install for numpy

Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\ELonni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-sri65vwf\numpy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ELonni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-fy0suk_9-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

```
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_lapack95,mkl_blas95,mkl_intel_c,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiomp5md,libifportmd not found in []
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

And I get a MK1 libraries not found but I adjusted the path and know its installed.

```
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

!! Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you thought about using conda rather than fighting with the numpy installation?

Comment: First off, you say you're using Python 2.7, but your error messages all have `C:\Python34` in them - which is it? Secondly, since you're on Windows, just use [`numpy+mkl`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository.

Comment: Thank you. A simple thing like that...My class requires 2.7 so now I have to uninstall Python 3.4. Do you know if I have to uninstall SSH keys as well ?

Answer (score 0):

For people receiving this type of error message please note, it was a conflict between Python 3.4 and libraries loaded for Python 2.7.  After removing the Python 3.4 files I reloaded Continuum and the required libraries loaded nicely.  Thank  you for your help peoples. and thank you  MattDMo